# Как сделать чтоб объект потомок не ссылался на объект родитель?

Tags: python, ооп

У меня проблема в том что созданный объект внутри класса ссылается на объект который создал его. Как исправить ?

```
import copy as cp
class a():
      lis = []
        
      def create_a(self):
          obj = cp.copy(a())
          print(obj.lis is self.lis) # True
     
    
 b = a()
        
 b.create_a()
Однако если:

a = []

b = []

a is b # false
```

Comment: def __init__() : self.lis = []

Comment: splash58 - В боевой задачи помимо самого родителя изменяться еще и другие потомки. Поэтому это не является решением

Comment: не понял - вы ссыдаетесь на переменную класса, а не ообъекта, но хотите,  чтобы они были разные у объектов одного класса ? не очевидно

Comment: splash58 - ошибься немного, исправил

Comment: splash58 - у меня еще функции рекурсивно в боевом проекте вызываться, и эта проблема с присваиванием есть

Comment: Danis - Однако если:

a = []

b = []

a is b # false

Answer (score 0):

Разница между `is` и `==`

Оператор `is` проверяет, чтобы оба операнда ссылались на один объект (т. е. проверяет, идентичны ли они друг другу).
Оператор `==` сравнивает значения операндов и проверяет на идентичность.
Так что `is` используется для эквивалентности ссылок, а `==` — для эквивалентности значений. Поясняющий пример:

```
>>> [] == []
True
>>> [] is [] # These are two empty lists at two different memory locations.
False
```

Comment: Serg Bocharov - спасибо за разъяснение для отвечающих, не знаешь случаем как сделать чтоб не ссылались ?)